# Did RViz become unit-aware?

Tags: ros, rviz, collada, collada-urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In a recent update?

I think to remember, that it was ignoring the unit information nested inside Collada files so far. That's why we had to add the scale parameter in our URDFs. Don't remember how RViz was/is handling STLs though.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59514/did-rviz-become-unit-aware?/) by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2062 on 2013-03-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes. This was apparently changed so that the same URDF can be used in ROS/RViz and Gazebo, and Gazebo apparently fixed this bug recently:

See these commits.

- https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/commit/e4711c55b4aa083494d936b005bfe88a901911a9
- https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/commit/cf398f59763826f8b8560e834a0a7a5796550fa2

Slightly later, the code was partially refactored to avoiding reading the XML repeatedly:

- https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/commit/b913d973a1c60cb038d9d9cb0fc269d57579d3de

This latest set of debs on groovy/public is the first to include a version of RVIZ with these changes (they've been on shadow-fixed for some time).

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-03-28**:
Im happy about the update itself, but I wonder how much the trouble it will cause, since nobody has been informed ...

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2013-03-29**:
Yeah, I ran across this problem when the MoveIt plugin stopped working properly, which is what spawned that second patch to avoid reading the XML. In theory though, any robot that now loads incorrectly in RVIZ was previously loading incorrectly in Gazebo, so at least now it can be fixed for good..